# How to merge mp4 audio dash fragment with another audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp4, mpeg-dash

I have 1 audio file from dash stream

```
 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file_191282-377206_header.mp4':   Metadata:

 major_brand     : iso6
 minor_version   : 1
 compatible_brands: mp42dashmsdhmsixiso6avc1isom
 creation_time   : 2016-04-29T11:04:26.000000Z   Duration: 00:00:30.02, start: 14.997333, bitrate: 49 kb/s
 Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 48 kb/s (default)
```

Also in exiftool output:

```
 Movie Data Size                 : 180193
 Movie Data Offset               : 6388
```

I try to merge with another audio and save metadata info like Movie Data Size/Offset and start/duration time. 
I try with ffmpeg/MP4Box commands like:

```
MP4Box -new -add file_191282-377206_header.mp4 -add out000.mp4
ffmpeg -i file_191282-377206_header.mp4 -i out000.mp4 -codec copy -shortest output.mp4
ffmpeg -i file_191282-377206_header.mp4 -i out000.mp4 -filter_complex amerge -ac 2 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

All the time information erased or changed.

So question is how to merge 2 audio files inside mp4 and not change Movie Size/Offset and start/duration time?

Answer (score 0):

Try to merge the **actual audio** (AAC) not the **media container** (MP4).
 
So extract the AAC from each media file, then merge those audios.
 
Finalise by putting the merged audio back into a new MP4 output.

Comment: When I put audio back into a new MP4 output I lose Duration: 00:00:30.02
and start: 14.997333